# How can we utilize application cache in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm planning to use in-memory cache in one of my apps deployed in cloud foundry which has multiple instances. Is the app memory shared by all instances or is it isolated for every instance? Couldn't get any info about this in the official documentation. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

App memory is not shared between application instances on Cloud Foundry.

Comment: @Shiva - You need to use a service if you want to share cache data. Redis, Gemfire, etc...